# difference between continue 2 and break in nested loops

Tags: php, loops, break, continue

I was refactoring some old code and stumbled on a `continue 2` that can be easily replaced with a break.

```
for($rows as $i){
      for($columns as $j){
           if( Helper::unicornExists($i, $j) ){
                 //continue 2;  
                 break;
           }
      }
}
```

If we say that `continue 2` makes the code more complicated and hard to read ,
is there any good reason to use it (in 2 level) nested loops ?

Comment: Just a `break` won't break out of the 2 nested loop it breaks out only 1 loop. You'll need `break 2` to break them both.

Comment: in this case is the same thing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this particular example it seems that it's the same thing and it is up to you to decide how you prefer it. One reason I can see to keep `continue 2` would be if in a future development of your project you would add something after the inner for

```
for($rows as $i){
      for($columns as $j){
           if( Helper::unicornExists($i, $j) ){
                 //continue 2;  
                 break;
           }
      }
      echo 'done with ', $i, PHP_EOL;
}
```

You need to think what you expect if the unicorn does exist. Do you want to skip just the inner loop, and that's what `break` would do, or you want to skip the outer one also, and that's what `continue 2` would do.

Comment: I would like to add that if you don't have any code in the outer loop after the inner loop, `continue 2` would be more readable because it communicates your intention better. `break` conveys the message that you want to stop or break out of something, while `continue n` conveys the message that you want to *skip to the next iteration*, which is the intention here.